# Adding a directory to Poetry .venv's PATH

Tags: visual-studio-code, python-venv, python-poetry

I have a library that installs precompiled binaries under the `.venv/bin` directory. However, the binary cannot be run from the command line (even after activating the Poetry venv), because `.venv/bin` is not part of the PATH.

How could I configure it such that `.venv/bin` is automatically added to the PATH variable when the .venv is activated?

I am on Windows, and this issue might be due to a specific library installing itself under `.venv/bin` when it should actually be using `.venv/Scripts` which is added to the PATH via the activate script.

Comment: `.venv/bin` should be in the `PATH` environment variable when the virtual environment is active. If not, then there is an issue somewhere. If I were you I would recreate the virtual environment from scratch. -- Note that you could also do `poetry run *command*` (without having to activate the virtual environment).

Comment: I think on Windows, it might only be adding the `.venv/Scripts` directory to the `PATH` environment.  In the `.venv/Scripts/activate.ps1` script, I only see a line that adds the `Scripts` directory and no reference to `bin`.

`$env:PATH = "$env:VIRTUAL_ENV/Scripts;" + $env:PATH`

Comment: OK. You might want to edit your question to clearly state that you are on Windows then. -- And I guess this library is the culprit then, I think it should not install anything in `bin` if it is on Windows, it should install itself in `Scripts`. But I do not know, I do not use Windows regularly, and I can not check.